# Auto mapping attribute from other table Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, globalization, edmx

I want to map some attributes of a class that generated from EDMX with the attribute from its virtual class(FK)

i.e.

```
public class Sign{
     public int SignId {get; set;}
     public string Text {get; set;}    
     public virtual ICollection<CultureSign> CultureSign {get; set;}
}

public class CultureSign{
     public int CultureSignId {get; set;}
     public string CultureCode {get; set;}
     public string Text {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Sign> Sign{get; set;}
}
```

how it stored data

Sign Table (default en-US content) **(Actually there are more attributes i.e. numeric value for logic)**

```
______________
|SignId| Text |
--------------
|1     | test |
--------------
```

CultureSign Table (Multi culture content)

```
________________________________
|CultureSignId|CutureCode| Text|
-------------------------------
|1            | ja-JP    |テスト|
--------------------------------
|2            | zh-CN    | 测试 |
--------------------------------
|3            | es-ES    |prueba|
--------------------------------
```

What I want is whenever I call method like..

```
var resultInJap = _signRepo.Get(1,"ja-JP").Text; //return "テスト"
var resultDefault = signRepo.Get(1).Text; //return "test"
```

I am thinking that just remove the "Text" column in base table and put "test" in Culture Table as "en-US" will be the solution but I do not want to re-structure the database and old code.

Kindly to get the recommendation for this,
Thank you

Comment: You are using LINQ or store procedure?

Comment: I use LINQ right now. Is there any way to inject or change the generated query from LINQ before execute the database without write it in the old way `(i.e. from Table select x)`? I actually write it in form of `(DataContext.Table.Where(expression))`.Otherwise to use `collection.select(m => new Model(){ a = m.culture.where(code).first.a })` is going to be mess for mapping the attribute with included table because there are many tables like this.